# Consume WCF service with post from ASP.NET's jQuery AJAX call

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, vb.net, wcf

I have read through lots of answers in the forum already about the questions and given that I am a complete fresher in this topic, please do apologize if anything in my questions is naïve.

I have an ASP.NET web application which should call a WCF service sends and returns a string [all on my local]

I am trying to call this service via jQuery and I am getting nowhere now. I am getting a 404-Not Found in my jQuery even though the WCF service is running in my local.

**My Web.Config File:**

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="aspnet:UseTaskFriendlySynchronizationContext" value="true" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior>
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>          
    </behaviors>            
    <protocolMapping>
        <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
    </protocolMapping>    
    <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

**This is the .svc file**

```
    <%@ ServiceHost Language="VB" 
Debug="true" 
Service="TemmeTaskSchedulerService.TemmeTaskSchedulerClass " 
CodeBehind="TemmeTaskScheduler.svc.vb" %>
```

**the interface**

```
<ServiceContract()>
Public Interface TemmeTaskSchedulerInterface
    <OperationContract()>            
    Function lstSearchProjects(ByVal environment As String) As String
End Interface
```

**the implementation file**

```
    Public Class TemmeTaskSchedulerClass
        Implements TemmeTaskSchedulerInterface

        Public Sub New()
        End Sub

            Function lstSearchProjects(ByVal environment As String) As String Implements TemmeTaskSchedulerInterface.lstSearchProjects
                  Return ""success "+environment 
        End Function
End class
```

**my jQuery call is as follows:**

```
$('#environment').change(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    url:'http://localhost:60403/TemmeTaskScheduler.svc/lstSearchProjects',
                    data: '{'+'$("#environment").children("option").filter(":selected").text()' + '}',//'{"Username": "' + $("#txtName").val() + '"}',
                    dataType: 'text',
                    processData: false,
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert("success:"+data);
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) { alert(xhr.status); alert(thrownError); }

                })
            });
```

Corrections and questions are much appreciated! :)

Comment: Where are you stuck? Are you getting any specific error message? It would be really helpful if you add your error message to your question.

Comment: I am getting a 404 when I call the service from my ASP.NET code.

Comment: Do you still get a 404 when you browse to the `http://localhost:60403/TemmeTaskScheduler.svc` with a web browser?

Comment: I am getting a HTTP 400 Bad request, I tried the following `http://localhost:60403/TemmeTaskScheduler.svc/lstSearchProjects http://localhost:60403/TemmeTaskScheduler.svc` and I got 400. 
When I tried executing my jquery , i get a 404 message :(

Comment: I'm assuming your app is in `c:/inetpub/wwwroot/TemmeTaskScheduler`. Is the TemmeTaskScheduler.svc file located at `c:/inetpub/wwwroot/TemmeTaskScheduler/TemmeTaskScheduler.svc`, or are there other folders within the TemmeTaskScheduler folder in wwwroot? For example, I have a site I can browse to at `http://localhost/dnn544`, and the url for the AjaxDataService.svc file in `C:/inetpub/wwwroot/dnn544/DesktopModules/IDoc/Services` would be `http://localhost/dnn544/DesktopModules/IDoc/Services/AjaxDataService.svc`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in wcf web.config file

```
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="webScriptEnablingBehavior">
      <enableWebScript/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>

  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="MyServiceTypeBehaviors">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

for info ...go to this link 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb763177(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: from what I read, they seem to be protocols of GET. But in jQuery I have mentioned it as POST. So is this code relevant for me? I am unsure... Please confirm for me once...

Comment: No..<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>, this is for wcf metaData. Above config work for all http methods. If you are using latest Visual studio, there is option to create ajax enabled Wcf service. There you can find only difference  "<enableWebScript/>" in web.config.